# firebug: search content of network panel responses/bodies

Tags: firebug, firefox-developer-tools

Before FF absorbed firebug, there was what could be (for me anyway) the most useful feature, which is now gone, or I can't figure out how to access it:

"Search within Net Panel" and check the box for "response bodies"

Is this feature now gone completely?

Answer (score 4):

This feature is [available since Firefox 53](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1334408). You can enable the advanced search by clicking the button with the magnifier glass in the toolbar of the *Network* panel.

[image: Advanced network request search]